# How to take value from combo box table microsoft dynamics ax 2012 x++ while select

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have table like
 (1st photo)
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9NGk.png)

What I should do to take this value to while select in x++?
 (2c photo)
[value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EAts.png)

Comment: You are going to need more detail to this question if you want us to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you would need to take the return from the lookup, find the value in the table via the returned value (key), and take the `Name` field.

So this would be the data in your case for the first result:

> `InventLocation::find('11').Name`

This is what's called a `lookup`. When you do a lookup, there are multiple methods that AX will determine what values to display. The one you're looking at is a lookup based upon the `Extended Data Type` relation.

- EDT - In this case `\Data Dictionary\Extended Data Types\InventLocationId`
- Table - which has a reference table of `\Data Dictionary\Tables\InventLocation`
- Primary Key - which has an alternate primary key of `\Data Dictionary\Tables\InventLocation\Indexes\InventLocationIdx`, which I believe in this case determines the return value
- AutoLookup - and the AutoLookup located at `\Data Dictionary\Tables\InventLocation\Field Groups\AutoLookup` determines which fields are displayed to the user as information.

If you want a custom lookup to return the `InventLocation.Name` field, you should look at the different methods available to you. This blog post is an excellent start to see different methods: https://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2009/04/lookup-methods-tutorial-custom-list.html